# Alternative ways to factory reset?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, factory-reset, bootloader

My Android 2.3 system  my PMP3384 tablet somehow crashed so seriously that I cannot even do a factory hard reset, because I cannot get to settings, only the following message appears again and again:

"Prestigio Home (process com.prestigio.android.launcher) stopped unexpectedly."
Actually this comes first and then a lot of other things, like calendar I have to force closed.

When I finally get to my Home screen this repeats itself.

I cannot get to bootloader because I dont have got hardware volume buttons...

Edit1: Oh yeah, I used it as a mass storage device before this happened. And a few power cycles before also used app2sd.

Comment: I got it!

I originally got a feeling that this happened because of the insufficent space on the device. But since I could not get into any apps I could not delete anything.

The solution: pulled down the pull-down menu, where there where a warning about insufficient memory, tap on that and now I could delete apps.

Answer (score 4):

According to the instructions in the device's [manual](http://marketing.prestigio.com/%24Customer_Support/Manuals/Tablet_PC/PMP3384/EN-PMP3384%20QSG%20v1.0.pdf) there should be a "reset" button on the back.  The manual does't have any information on how to use it, but I'd try pushing the button while the device is on, or turning it on while having this button pressed.

Answer (score 3):

Try starting it in [safe mode](http://androinica.com/2010/08/how-to-activate-android%E2%80%99s-safe-mode-to-get-out-of-a-force-close-loop/)

If you have a HOME button - try keeping it depressed as you power up the device.

Answer (score 0):

Enter into recovery mode by pressing HOME button while powering up the device .
It will show you an option as factory reset use volume buttons to scroll up/down and home button to select.
and select yes and yes to all always.