# factory reset a device having no volume keys

Tags: factory-reset

I got a device that I have to reset to factory settings because the owner of the device has forgotten its password. I checked `Debugging` is not enabled.

I have seen various suggestions on how to reset a device but all suggestion involve volume keys. Unfortunately this device **doesn't** have any volume or other key, there is just only one power key.

**Device:** `XPOD Tabloid 7''`

How do it reset it ? or unlock the device. any suggestions?

Comment: Related: [Problem with resetting Simply Tabletz tablet, no reset or volume buttons](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/73099/16575), which unfortunately has no answers. I remember we had another one with details, but unfortunately I cannot find it currently. Ah, hrere it is: [Alternative ways to factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21360/16575)

Comment: Check carefully the back of your phone for a little hole used to reset phones (if held together with the power button you should get to recovery or reset)
I don't know how in the world you are gonna use the recovery with no volume buttons but in the recovery you usually can use adb.

Comment: Yes got it. I told the owner to reset it as you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: You could use a touch recovery like Team Win?